# How do I make a button that plays a song whenever I press it stop the song as soon as I press it again?

Tags: java, android, button, mp3, firebase-storage

i have a button that when pressed, plays a mp3 file that it gets from firebase storage, the problem is that if i press the button twice the audio overlaps. how do I make the audio pause when I press the button again? i'm sorry if this question was answered before but i'm new and it's hard for me to understand if its not in my individual case.

````
 button2=findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
                    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    player.setDataSource("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/yovoicest2.appspot.com/o/songs%2FDeath.mp3?alt=media&token=925d52c3-e5a7-4b2c-a598-e83a97730a24");
                    player.prepare();
                    player.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
        });```
````

Answer (score 1):

Define the Media Player as a Member variable and check.

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
button2=findViewById(R.id.button2);
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(player != null && player.isPlaying()) {
            // Handle the playing like changing the button Text/Image
            player.stop();
        } else {
            // Handle the stop like changing the button Text/Image
            //Do your thing. Initialize it again with whatever file you want.
        }
    }
});
```